# Identifying forwarded WhatsApp Messages

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I would like to explain a scenario. Our users can send voice note to our WhatsApp chatbot and we can grab the audio using the `MediaUrl0` from the callback url. However, we want to be able to check if a previously submitted voice note is being forwarded again to our chatbot. Is there a way for us to determine if the voice note has been previously submitted?

From Twilio's callback, the `MediaUrl0` is different for the same voice note.

For example, this is the url of original voicenote -

```
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages/MM3467ba9a036512d8afd474aaf7274d26/Media/MEfd990e8bbd8de74bc1dd63632f8a08fe
```

When this same voicenote is forwarded, the `MediaUrl0` becomes -

```
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages/MMd5af70ae67c9971ec84ff45f4ba43a24/Media/MEa6f2534517236f810d19a49368e10671
```

As you can see, the URLs are different so its  difficult for me to do a check.

Comment: Is this question related with laravel tag?

Comment: Curious if you run an MD5/SHA hash on the resulting media file, if they are the same. You could use that to determine if the file was the same.

Comment: @Alan any pointers on how to do this?

Comment: I don't. There are different libraries for languages which can add hashing. Basically a hash takes in variable input and comes up with a fixed length output (hash). You can then compare the hash to see if the files are identical. If you have OS-X, you can take a look at this via terminal, running `shasum --help`.